# Ordenar texto con numeros y caracteres IQueryable c#

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Estoy teniendo un problema de ordenamiento de texto, necesito ordenar el campo de Codigo, pero el campo dicho es de tipo **string**, el problema esta que cuando ordeno, lo hace de una manera que no la necesito

```cs
[Route("api/xxxx/xxxx")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(RackViewModel))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetRack(
            string sortName = "bodega",
            string sortOrder = "asc",
            ...
            )
        {
            int count = 0;
            IQueryable<RackViewModel> Racks = from Rack in db.WMS_RACK
                                              select new RackViewModel
                                              {
                                                Bodega = Rack.WRA_BODEGA,
                                                Codigo = Rack.WRA_CODIGO,
                                                Pasillo = Rack.WRA_PASILLO,
                                                ...
                                                };

            if (bodega != null) {
                Racks = Racks.Where(s => s.Bodega.Equals(bodega));
            }
            ...
            if (estado == "ACTIVA") {
                Racks = Racks.Where(s => s.Activa.Equals(true));
            }
            if (estado == "INACTIVA")
            {
                Racks = Racks.Where(s => s.Activa.Equals(false));
            }

            count = Racks.Count();

            switch (sortName)
            {
                case "Codigo":
                    Racks = sortOrder == "asc" ? Racks.OrderBy(s => s.Codigo) : Racks.OrderByDescending(s => s.Codigo);
                    break;

                   ...

                case "Zona":
                    Racks = sortOrder == "asc" ? Racks.OrderBy(s => s.Zona) : Racks.OrderByDescending(s => s.Zona);
                    break;
                default:
                    Racks = sortOrder == "asc" ? Racks.OrderBy(s => s.Codigo) : Racks.OrderByDescending(s => s.Codigo);

                    break;
            }
            int page0 = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
            Racks = Racks.Skip(() => page0).Take(() => pageSize);
            return Ok( new PagedResult<RackViewModel>(Racks,pageNumber,pageSize,count));
        }
```

lo esta ordenando de esta manera, que no debe ser asi

[image: Imagen]

lo que necesito es que se ordene de la siguiente manera:
   `"01",  "02",  "011",  "A1",  "A2",  "A10"`

realmente no se como hacer tal cosa, estuve googleando pero no encontre algo que me pueda ayudar, aprecio tu ayuda y muchas gracias

Comment: Que sentido tiene esa ordenación?. Parece un orden de tipo **Int + String**, en el cual los números tienen un orden anterior a las letras, y así sucesivamente. Es un tipo de ordenación ya **tipificada**? o te la has inventado tú. Yo por lo menos no la conozco, y si no existe deberás hacer tu mismo el algoritmo de ordenación en función de tus necesidades.

Comment: Pues no todas las veces va a ser **Int + String**, ahi no se sabe como va a ingresar los caracteres el usuario, en este caso esta **String + Int**